# Create new subfolder with same name and move files to the new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need your help to complete a windows batch (.cmd) file to create a new folder based on parent folder name and move some files to the new folder.

(both directory names and/or file names will be always different and may have space chars or dots)

I managed to created the folder based on current dir name but I cant figure how to move the files to the new folder. I'm using this in a button in Total Commander that's is working partially.

I'm not programmer, only have a very basic knowledge of batch. I was searching a lot of examples and trying but I could not find the way.
Thanks in advance.

I Have this:

```
D:\Artist - Album\   <--- current start path
   ├──01-track1.wav
   ├──01-track1.flac
   ├──02-track2.wav
   ├──02-track2.flac
```

Running this line to successfully create subfolder based on parent name: "Artist - Album (FLAC)"

```
for %%* in (.) do md "%%~n* (FLAC)"
```

Results in:

```
D:\Artist - Album\
   ├───\Artist - Album (FLAC)\   <--- new folder OK!
   ├─01-track1.wav
   ├─01-track1.flac
   ├─02-track2.wav
   ├─02-track2.flac
```

What I want is move the .flac files inside that new folder like this:

```
D:\Artist - Album\
   ├───\Artist - Album (FLAC)\   ┐
   │    ├─01-track1.flac         ├ ?
   │    └─02-track2.flac         ┘
   ├─01-track1.wav
   └─02-track2.wav
```

Comment: `md "%cd% (FLAC)" & move *.flac "%cd% (FLAC)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in (.) do md "%%~na (FLAC)"&move "*.flac" ".\%%~na (FLAC)\"
```

`&` cascades commands.

(untested)

Please don't use symbols as metavariables - only alphas are documented (and presumably supported) *and* `*` and many other symbols have a special meaning to batch.

Comment: You can _technically_ use any of the 128 basic ASCII characters for metavariables, but only letters are recommended.

Comment: Tested, it works perfectly! thanks
and thanks for your recomendations ;)